# Creating logback logger programmatically

Tags: java, logback

I have a problem regarding to logback project. My requirement is I have to create log properties dynamically. Let me explain this by an example.

My project creates socket communication with external system and it may have multiple sockets. For each socket, I want to have different log files which will contain the messages that is read and sent. To accomplish this, I create the logger for sockets programmatically. Problem is when I want to reconfigure loggers based on logback.xml (by adding scan="true" or by reinitializing the logback), the loggers I created becomes unusable. How can I fixed that or can you advise me another solution?

This is my configuration file (logback.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <property name="HOME_PATH" value="/data/logs/myapp/" scope="CONTEXT" />
    <property name="MYAPP_LOG_FILE" value="myapp.log" />
    <property name="MYAPP_ROLLING_TEMPLATE" value="%d{yy-MM-dd}" scope="CONTEXT" />
    <property name="MYAPP_OLD_LOG_FILE" value="${MYAPP_LOG_FILE}.%d{yy-MM-dd}" />
    <property name="DEFAULT_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%file:%line] [%level] %msg%n" scope="CONTEXT" />

    <appender name="myAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_PATH}${MYAPP_LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${HOME_PATH}${MYAPP_LOG_FILE}.${MYAPP_ROLLING_TEMPLATE}</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>${DEFAULT_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.myapp" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="myAppender" />
    </logger>

    <root level="OFF">
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and here you can see how I create loggers programmatically (again, I do this only for socket logs).

```
public static Logger createLogger(String name) {
        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger templateLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LogUtil.getLogger("com.myapp");
        LoggerContext context = templateLogger.getLoggerContext();

        String logDir = context.getProperty("HOME_PATH");

        PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        encoder.setPattern(context.getProperty("DEFAULT_PATTERN"));
        encoder.setContext(context);

        DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> timeBasedTriggeringPolicy = new DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
        timeBasedTriggeringPolicy.setContext(context);

        TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent> timeBasedRollingPolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy<ILoggingEvent>();
        timeBasedRollingPolicy.setContext(context);
        timeBasedRollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(logDir + name + ".log." + context.getProperty("MYAPP_ROLLING_TEMPLATE"));
        timeBasedRollingPolicy.setTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy(timeBasedTriggeringPolicy);
        timeBasedTriggeringPolicy.setTimeBasedRollingPolicy(timeBasedRollingPolicy);

        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rollingFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        rollingFileAppender.setAppend(true);
        rollingFileAppender.setContext(context);
        rollingFileAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
        rollingFileAppender.setFile(logDir + name + ".log");
        rollingFileAppender.setName(name + "Appender");
        rollingFileAppender.setPrudent(false);
        rollingFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(timeBasedRollingPolicy);
        rollingFileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(timeBasedTriggeringPolicy);

        timeBasedRollingPolicy.setParent(rollingFileAppender);

        encoder.start();
        timeBasedRollingPolicy.start();

        rollingFileAppender.stop();
        rollingFileAppender.start();

        ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logbackLogger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LogUtil.getLogger(name);
        logbackLogger.setLevel(templateLogger.getLevel());
        logbackLogger.setAdditive(false);
        logbackLogger.addAppender(rollingFileAppender);

        return logbackLogger;
}
```

And this is how I reinitialize logback

```
private static void initializeLogback() {
    File logbackFile = new File(logFilePath);
    System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", logbackFile.getAbsolutePath());
    StaticLoggerBinder loggerBinder = StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton();
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) loggerBinder.getLoggerFactory();

    loggerContext.reset();
    JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
    configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
    try {
        configurator.doConfigure(logbackFile);
    } catch( JoranException e ) {
        throw new ColumbusRuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need the [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) where your discriminator would be the socket id itself, or any combined variation. I dunno what threading issues you'll run into with this (when MDC is read, etc), but this should be a good starting point and seems similar to your case.

Comment: In logback manual http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html, it is written that "logback-classic assumes that values are placed into the MDC with moderate frequency". can it handle 1000 requests per second? What is the TPS interval when we talk about "moderate frequency"?

Comment: Not sure. You can contact the author, or post onto the mailing list. I just had remembered reading about this and thought it similar to your issue.

Comment: I post this question to the mailing list and Ceki returned a response. Here it is: "I think 1000 MDC modifications should be OK. Look at LogbackMDCAdapter [1] for details.

Cheers,

[1] [link]http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/LogbackMDCAdapter.html"