# Groovy + write log to file + Inject Logging Using Annotations

Tags: groovy

I create the following groovy script in order to show how to inject a log field into our classes with a simple annotation

```
// File: LogSlf4j.groovy
// Add dependencies for Slf4j API and Logback

@Grapes([

       @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.6.1'),
       @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='0.9.28')
])

 import org.slf4j.*
 import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

 // Use annotation to inject log field into the class.
 @Slf4j

 class faimily{

 def father() {


    log.debug 'car engine is hot'
    log.error 'my car is stuck'
}


    def mother() {


    log.debug 'dont have a water in the kitchen'
    log.error 'Cant make a cake'
}


}

 def helloWorld = new faimily()
 helloWorld.father()
 helloWorld.mother()
```

when I run the groovy script I get the following results ( on GROOVY CONSOLE )

```
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] DEBUG faimily - car engine is hot
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] ERROR faimily - my car is stuck
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] DEBUG faimily - dont have a water in the kitchen
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] ERROR faimily - Cant make a cake
```

please advice how we can print the results to a log file in the WIN machine , and what need to add to my groovy script in order to enable that?

for example:

the log file

> C:\Program Files\LOGS\my.groovy.log

( should contain the results: )

```
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] DEBUG faimily - car engine is hot
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] ERROR faimily - my car is stuck
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] DEBUG faimily - dont have a water in the kitchen
 17:58:50.938 [Thread-59] ERROR faimily - Cant make a cake
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@Grab('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1')
@Grab('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:0.9.28')

import org.slf4j.*
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import ch.qos.logback.core.*
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.*

// Use annotation to inject log field into the class.
@Slf4j
class Family {
    static {
        new FileAppender().with {
            name = 'file appender'
            file = 'C:\\tmp\\groovy.log'
            context = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()
            encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder().with {
                context = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()
                pattern = "%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n"
                start()
                it
            }
            start()
            log.addAppender(it)
        }
    }

    def father() {
        log.debug 'car engine is hot'
        log.error 'my car is stuck'
    }

    def mother() {
        log.debug 'dont have a water in the kitchen'
        log.error 'Cant make a cake'
    }
}

def helloWorld = new Family()
helloWorld.father()
helloWorld.mother()
```

Comment: Hi tim – ( first +1 for you ) , I have question – is your additional code include file log rotation ?, if not how we solve the issue if log became huge capacity ?

Comment: No, you'd need a RollingFileAppender. Soz, that wasn't in your question, so I left it out! I'll come up with something when I get to a pc

Comment: Found this which might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060545/creating-logback-logger-programmatically

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t understand how I can push this solution to your code , it’s not simple ( because I very new in groovy ) , or maybe you can resolve the solution in your code – then it will help me allot

Comment: Hi Tim
I have another question according to our code implementation, something is missing here , 
I guess that should be some file configuration that responsible to which log we want , for example in case we want to see only DEBIG lines in the logs , then need to set the configuration file in order to get that , so please can tell us how to set this file and how to configure it ?

Comment: Hi Tim - if you want I can ask this on new quastion ,