# Simple Groovy Logback Configuration for Multiple Scripts

Tags: logging, groovy, logback

I have the following:

C:\Scripts\Groovy\foo.groovy

```
@Grab (group = 'ch.qos.logback', module = 'logback-classic', version = '1.1.3')
def logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger ('foo')
logger.info ("Hello, Foo!')
```

C:\Scripts\Groovy\bar.groovy

```
@Grab (group = 'ch.qos.logback', module = 'logback-classic', version = '1.1.3')
def logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger ('bar')
logger.info ("Hello, Bar!')
```

Scripts are executed via `groovy foo.bar` and `groovy bar.groovy` respectively.

Questions:

1. What lines of code can be added to each script to append log
   messages to "foo.log" and "bar.log" respectively?
2. Can individual
       configuration files be created, for example "logback_foo.groovy" and
       "logback_bar.groovy", to append log messages to log files?
3. Can a
       common configuration file, for example "logback.groovy", be used to
       append messages to log files for each script?

I have multiple small utility scripts and do not want to go through the effort of setting up a Gradle project for each script.  I do utilize Gradle for significant projects and I have been successful in getting a larger project functional.

I am new to both Groovy and LogBack so please provide contents of each script/configuration file and commands to execute the scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1. You can directly add a `FileAppender` in a static initializer as shown in the answer of this question: [Groovy + write log to file + Inject Logging Using Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412464/groovy-write-log-to-file-inject-logging-using-annotations)
2. You can also combine the above with individual configuration files for each script:

**`logback_foo.groovy`**:

```
foo {
    file = 'foo.log'
}
```

and use `ConfigSlurper` to read it:

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('logback_foo.groovy').toURL())
assert config.foo.file == 'foo.log'
```

3. But IMHO, the best way is to do it is to leverage [*logback's native groovy configuration*](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) with `logback.groovy`, so that:

**`logback.groovy`**: (logback configuration)

```
appender('console', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] - %msg%n"
    }
}

appender('foo', FileAppender) {
    file = 'foo.log'
    append = true
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] - %msg%n"
    }
}

appender('bar', FileAppender) {
    file = 'foo.log'
    append = true
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] - %msg%n"
    }
}

logger('Foo', INFO, ['console', 'foo'])
logger('Bar', INFO, ['bar'])
```

and **`foo.groovy`**: (`bar.groovy` would be similar)

```
@Grapes([
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true),
    @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.1.3')
])

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class Foo {
    static main(args) {
        log.debug 'Foo debug'
        log.info  'Foo info'
        log.warn  'Foo warn'
        log.error 'Foo error'
    }
}
```